# Keeping excel-like pivot with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an xlsx with 2 worksheet. 
In the first sheet I have an Excel pivot, in the second one the data source for the pivot table.
I would like to modify the data source via python keeping the pivot structure in the other sheet.

Opening the woorkbook with openpyxl I lost the pivot table, does anyone know if there is an option to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Use the openpyxl package version 2.5 above, the function to keep the pivot table format is only available from the 2.5 release onward.